# Excel file importing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a different excel files with same headers. Now I want to import in MS SQL Server 2012.

Can somebody help me to achieve this?

Comment: Please be more specific on your question and provide some code on how you've tried to solve it.

Comment: Actually i tried many path .i am not getting any answers..

Comment: You can try SSIS or right click on the database in your SQL server management studio start the Import Data wizard. The wizard creates a script which cane be saved and run again later.

Comment: have you tried Import/Export tool of SQL Server

Comment: Have you searched on StackOverflow? [Plenty of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=import+excel+sql+server)